# How to show that $\overline {f}$ is continuous on $\widehat {A} \cup \{\varphi_{0}\}\ $?

Tags: continuity, compactness, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

> Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra and $\widehat A$ be the space of all non-zero multiplicative linear functionals on $A$ equipped with the Gelfand topology. Let $f \in C \left (\widehat {A} \right ),$ the space of all complex valued continuous functions on $\widehat {A}.$ Let $\varphi_{0}$ denote the zero linear functional on $A.$ Consider the function $\overline {f} : \widehat {A} \cup \left \{\varphi_{0} \right \} \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ by $$\overline {f} (\varphi) = \begin{cases} f(\varphi) & \varphi \in \widehat {A} \\ 0 & \varphi = \varphi_{0} \end{cases}$$ If $\widehat {A}$ is compact then show that $\overline {f}$ is continuous on $\widehat {A} \cup \left \{\varphi_{0} \right \}.$

I am trying to show that inverse image of a closed set under $\overline {f}$ is closed. Although I can able to show it for closed subsets of $\mathbb C$ not containing $0$; I find it difficult to show when I consider a closed set containing $0.$ Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what topology you consider on $\tilde A=\widehat A\cup\{\varphi_0\}$. Assuming you are considering the weak$^*$ topology on $\tilde A$, this is a Hausdorff topology, so compact sets are closed.  As $\widehat A$ is compact you have that $\varphi_0$ is a point on the complement of $A$, which is open. So you can define $\bar f$ to be whatever you want at $\varphi_0$, and it will still be continuous.

Comment: Is it possible to describe the continuity of $\overline {f}$ using convergence of nets? In case we have a sequence in $\widetilde {A}$ converging to $\varphi_{0}$ then it is eventually constant otherwise we can extract a subsequence in $\widehat {A}$ converging to $\varphi_{0}$ which implies $\varphi_{0} \in \widehat {A}$ (since $\widehat {A}$ is compact), a contradiction. Can it be possible to give similar arguments using nets?

Comment: If you have a net $x_j\to\varphi_0$, choose a neighbourhood $V$ of $\varphi_0$ disjoint with $\widehat A$. Then $x_j\in V$ for all $j$ beyond a certain fixed $j_0$; for all these points, $x_j=\varphi_0$; so,  $|\bar f(x_j)-\bar f(x_k)|=0$ for all $k,j\geq j_0$.

Comment: Oh I see now. $\{\varphi_{0}\}$ is open in $\widetilde {A} = \widehat {A} \cup \{\varphi_{0}\}.$ This is what I missed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's a good way of seeing it.